# How to order frequency counts of categorical variables by group facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create bar graphs of categorical data ordered by frequency within groups. For example, using the diamonds dataset, I would like bar graphs ordered by counts/ frequency of "clarity" values grouped by "cut."

```
data(diamonds)
library(tidyverse)

diamonds$cut <- as.character(diamonds$cut)
diamonds$clarity <- as.character(diamonds$clarity)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(clarity, order = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(clarity = as.factor(reorder(clarity, n))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, clarity, fill = cut)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ cut, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "count", y = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
```

This produces the following graph:
[image]

It is very close to what I want, but the only graph actually ordered by clarity frequency is the first, "Fair." How can I make the all the bar graphs ordered by clarity frequency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to keep facet_wrap?

Comment: Hi @YacineHajji, not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `reorder_within` and `scale_y_reorderd` from the `tidytext` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidytext)

diamonds$cut <- as.character(diamonds$cut)
diamonds$clarity <- as.character(diamonds$clarity)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  count(clarity, order = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(clarity = tidytext::reorder_within(clarity, n, cut)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, clarity, fill = cut)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "count", y = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, if you have differently ordered y axes on each plot, then I would argue you have five distinct plots rather than a single faceted plot. You could therefore draw it as such:

```r
plots <- lapply(levels(factor(diamonds$cut)), function(x) {
  diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(clarity, order = FALSE) %>% 
  filter(cut == x) %>%
  mutate(clarity = as.factor(reorder(clarity, n))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n, clarity)) +
  geom_col(fill = scales::hue_pal()(5)[match(x, levels(factor(diamonds$cut)))])+
  labs(title = x, x = "count", y = NULL) +
  theme_bw()
  }
)

library(patchwork)

  (plots[[1]] + plots[[2]]) / 
  (plots[[3]] + plots[[4]]) / 
  (plots[[5]] + plot_spacer())
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!! This is a perfect work-around; I am so grateful for your time and help.